# read data per ID from firebase into spinner

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I would like read data from firebase into spinner, and the spinner should contain data per ID. There is two spinner, color & size, but what I got is all data from all ID. How i can fix this issue?

The firebase data structure like image below :

[image]

and here is my code :

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference AttrReference = reference.child("Products").child("Attribut");
....

private void getAttributProduct() {
    AttrReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            colorList = new ArrayList<>();
            sizeList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot child : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        AttrProduk attr = child.getValue(AttrProduk.class);
                        list.add(attr);
                        colorList.add(attr.getColor());
                        sizeList.add(attr.getSize());

                        showSpinnerSize(sizeList);
                        showSpinnerColor(colorList);
                        showStock(attr.getStock());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

private void showSpinnerSize(List<String> dataSize) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataSize);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spSize.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void showSpinnerColor(List<String> dataColor) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataColor);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spColor.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void showStock(String data) {
    stock.setText(data+" Pcs");
}
```

And here is what i got, based on database it should get data per ID :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the spinner to show data related to a key, then you need to do a query:

```
DatabaseReference AttrReference = reference.child("Products").child("Attribut");
Query query=AttrReference.orderByKey().equalTo(key_id);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {..}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#orderByKey()

Comment: where i can get key_id?

Comment: @Asqa the key_id you need to retrieve the id from the database, for example associate the id with a trademark, then when the user clicks on the trademark and clicks on the spinner, you will be able to use the id of that trademark

Comment: base on my structure database above the id is -LENmVCxJHy1dZq9W-Xf & -LEib0TQm41w8lrc3j7R right?

Comment: no the id is one of those, since that is what you wanted, so this `-LENmVCxJHy1dZq9W-Xf` will be inside here `orderByKey().equalTo(-LENmVCxJHy1dZq9W-Xf);`